# custom rxjs operator (buffer) prevent Angular app from being stable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on a custom rxjs operator for extending the `bufferTime` operator functionality.
BufferTime takes timespan and optionally max size of the buffer, in my case however, I need to reset buffer not only based on time & size but also on the additional trigger - routeChange.

I've created a custom operator to handle that, it takes timeSpan, maxSize and trigger$, creates observables for timeSpan buffer and size buffer, and finally merges those 3 together and pass as a single notifier for the `buffer` operator.

Here is the source code:

```js
function bufferFrom<T>(...triggers: Observable<any>[]): (source$: Observable<T>) => Observable<T[]> {
   // restart Subject used for taking control over all triggers and resetting them on emit
   const restart: Subject<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);

   // function that wraps trigger with restart Observable to take control over that
   const withRestart: <R>(source: Observable<R>) => Observable<R> = <R>(source: Observable<R>) => restart.asObservable().pipe(switchMap(() => source));

   // create Observable from all triggers connected with restart control
   const bufferTrigger = merge(...triggers.map(withRestart));

   // emit first reset to enable Observables initially
   restart.next();
 
   // return the source$ Observable with buffer, and reset applied after buffer is emitted
   return source$ => source$.pipe(
      buffer(bufferTrigger),
      tap(() => restart.next()),
      filter(items => items.length > 0),
   );
}

export function bufferAll<T>(bufferTimeSpan: number, bufferSize: number, trigger$: Observable<any>): (source$: Observable<T>) => Observable<T[]> {
   return (source$) => {
      const size$ = source$.pipe(bufferCount(bufferSize));
      const timeSpan$ = source$.pipe(bufferTime(bufferTimeSpan * 1000));

      return source$.pipe(bufferFrom(size$, timeSpan$, trigger$));
   };
}
```

The issue I have is that in Angular app using such operator in Service provided in root causes the app to be unstable which blocks rendering of the App.

Here is how I tried to run the code outside of the Angular Zone, but that is not working in my case. However, if I use a simple `bufferTime` instead of my implementation it works fine with the code below.

```js
 this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    const routeChanges$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd));

    this.dataSubject.asObservable().pipe(
      // Send after 60 seconds or when 10 items in buffer or when route changes
      bufferAll(60, 10, routeChanges$),
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      this.zone.run(() => console.log(data));
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why my operator blocks Angular, and `bufferTime` doesn't, because they both are creating infinite Observables based on the time/intervals, which according to Angular docs https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#isstable-examples-and-caveats
could be a problem that blocks render and app stable state.

Any idea what could be possibly wrong in my implementation, what have I missed?

**Added a short [stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/buffer-all-operator?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

data.service.ts includes custom operator code as well as normal usage of `bufferTime` or `bufferCount` operators. When using `bufferTime` or `bufferCount`operators app is being stable, if commented out and switched to my operator is becoming permanently unstable.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/50785257/19768317, By the way your restart ReplaySubject never complete.